# Alamofire unable to cast header as HTTPHeaders to pass in for Multi-part PUT request

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, swift5

I've been trying to upload photo/video content using multipart method from Alamofire 5.2.1 before, but it did not seem to allow to pass in headers (Authentication/Content-type) parameters so I downgraded to Alamofire 4.8 to try and see if it is much stabler.

[image]
** Shown here is a `.post` request but I am doing in my code a `.put` method.

Why do I keep getting this issue (in the screenshot) when attempting to pass the header as `HTTPHeaders` ? It is saying as follows:

**Error:**

```
Cannot convert value of type 'HTTPHeaders' (aka 'Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>') to expected argument type 'HTTPHeaders?' (aka 'Optional<Dictionary<String, String>>')
```

Anyway to solve this?

The header is listed on top of the method as follows:

```
let requestHeaders: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "THIS_IS_A_TOKEN",
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    ]
```

and clearly defined the dictionary of type HTTPHeaders for Alamofire (and Alamofire Imported by the way).

Answer (score 4):

You have defined headers wrongly.

```
var reuqestHeaders: HTTPHeaders
requestHeaders = HTTPHeaders = [
 "Authorization": "....",
 "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"]()
```

You did like this.

Just define requestHeaders as following.

```
let reuqestHeaders : HTTPHeaders = [
  "Authorization": "....",
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `()` after your dictionary literal. It should just be:

```swift
let headers = [ 
    // Header values.
]
```